# How to get param from ionic cli to local project

Tags: build, ionic2, parameter-passing, ionic-cli

I have a command: `ionic build android`

In my opinion, when entered, it'll run file **build.js** from `ionic cli`  in my OS to my local project.
But I didn't see any platform param in local project.

So my question here is, how to get param `android` from ionic cli to local project.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the android platform to your ionic project?. i.e. ran `ionic platform add android`?

Comment: Yes, I did. My problem is how to control where it calls `run android`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out. 
Try to find `ionic-cli` in `node-modules` at your OS drives.

It's where command: `ionic build android` is executed.